# Can the SQL Replace Function be used for multiple values?

Tags: sql, function, replace

I have a bunch of invoices in a SQL table which have a field called "Status".

There a two possible statuses: "P" or "U".

I want to select all invoices however, I want to replace all instances of the "P" with "Posted" and all instances of "U" with "Unapproved".

The following query does exactly what I want, but for only one record at a time.

```
Replace(Type, 'U', 'Unapproved')
```

How can I get the "Replace" function to work in such a way that all records in the column are replaced with either "Posted" or "Unapproved"?

For example, I want to change this table:

```
+-----------+--------+
| Invoice # | Status |
+-----------+--------+
| 00001921  | P      |
| 00001932  | P      |
| 0001937   | P      |
| 00890483  | U      |
| 00902945  | U      |
| 08MAY14   | P      |
| 1012      | P      |
| 10619     | P      |
| 10620     | P      |
| 10633     | P      |
| 10641     | P      |
| 130       | P      |
| 1303      | P      |
| 1307      | P      |
| 217731    | U      |
| 2714      | U      |
| 2720      | P      |
| 6523      | P      |
| 712       | P      |
+-----------+--------+
```

Into this:

```
+-----------+------------+
| Invoice # |   Status   |
+-----------+------------+
| 1921      | Posted     |
| 1932      | Posted     |
| 1937      | Posted     |
| 890483    | Unapproved |
| 902945    | Unapproved |
| 8-May-14  | Posted     |
| 1012      | Posted     |
| 10619     | Posted     |
| 10620     | Posted     |
| 10633     | Posted     |
| 10641     | Posted     |
| 130       | Posted     |
| 1303      | Posted     |
| 1307      | Posted     |
| 217731    | Unapproved |
| 2714      | Unapproved |
| 2720      | Posted     |
| 6523      | Posted     |
| 712       | Posted     |
+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these 2 statemens:

```
Update table set status = 'Unapproved' where status = 'U'
```

and

```
Update table set status = 'Posted' where status = 'P'
```

Sounds like you want a select statement with a case in it:

```
SELECT   
  CASE 
     WHEN status =  'P' THEN 'Posted'
     WHEN status = 'U' THEN 'Unapproved'
  END
FROM [table]
```

Comment: Replace table with the actual name of your table.

Comment: Does this permanently update the table? That is not what I want to do.

Comment: Yes, that updates your table. I added a select with a case statement that should work for you.

Comment: Is it possible to display the results as "Posted" or "Unapproved" however, not affect the actual data?

Comment: The second part of the answer shows how to display it without updating the data. The one that starts with Select Case.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE SampleTable
SET [Status] = CASE [Status]
    WHEN 'P' THEN 'Posted'
    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Unapproved'
END
```

**SELECT:**

```
SELECT Invoice, 
    [Status] = CASE [Status]
                WHEN 'P' THEN 'Posted'
                WHEN 'U' THEN 'Unapproved'
                END 
FROM SampleTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The replace statements have to be nested.

```
SELECT `Invoice #`, 
       REPLACE( REPLACE (STATUS, 'U', 'UNAPPROVED') , 'P', 'POSTED') 
       as `STATUS` from Table;
```

where Table is the name of whatever your table is.

EDIT: Don't do this.

Comment: This produces an error:

Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
The replace function requires 3 argument(s).

Comment: Sorry.  I was sloppy.  I think I fixed it.

Comment: So, this will [replace every `P` in `UNAPPROVED` with `POSTED`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/39049)? Nice. :)